# Como hago para que se mantenga activo el botón seleccionado en html

Tags: html, css, foundation

Tengo 3 botones en un grupo de botones en un menú (Foundation), quiero que al seleccionar cualquiera de ellos se pinte de otro color o se resalte hasta que seleccione otro entonces el cambio de color o resaltado cambia a nuevo botón seleccionado.

Comment: Hola para eso tienes las pseudo clases hover, active y focus;  si colocas tu codigo puedo ayudarte..

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

Usa las pseudoclases `:hover` y `:focus` para darle estilos a un elemento al pasar sobre él y al seleccionarlo:

```css
.navegacion{
    background: #89119d;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 2rem;
}

.navegacion__enlace{
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 3rem;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

body{
    background: #9c27b0;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

/*Al pasar el mouse es naranja claro, al hacer click es naranja oscuro*/

a:hover{
    color: orange;
}

a:focus{
    color:orangered;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navegacion">
    <a href="#" class="navegacion__enlace navegacion__enlace">Tienda</a>
    <a href="#" class="navegacion__enlace">Nosotros</a>
</nav>
```